# Testing Express route where that route has a callback

Tags: express, callback, nock

I want to mock a curl request to an express route that calls an api. I've found a lot of documentation on how to do this but I've been having issues because there is a call back in my code.

```
var request = require('request')

function queryConsul(req, res) {
  var options = {
      url: 'http://10.244.68.3:8500/v1/catalog/node/services'
  };

  request(options, callback)

  function callback(error, response, body) {
    console.log("hola?");
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      response=body
    }
    res.send(response)
  }
}

module.exports = queryConsul;
```

When I run my current test I get a Error: timeout of 200ms

Here is my test, I've tried to use nock as a stubbing service, any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

```
var queryConsul = require("../../../helper/queryConsulService");
var expect = require("chai").expect;
var nock = require("nock");

describe("Consul API Queries", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    var consulResponse =
    {
     "Node": {
     "Node": "Services",
     "Address": "some_address",
     "TaggedAddresses": null,
     "CreateIndex": 72389,
     "ModifyIndex": 72819
 },
 "Services": {
     "OneBitesTheDust": {
         "ID": "OneBitesTheDust",
         "Service": "OneBitesTheDust",
         "Tags": ["{\"Type\" : \"service type\", \"Description\": \"ddfadf\"}"],
         "Address": "www.google.com",
         "Port": 80,
         "EnableTagOverride": false,
         "CreateIndex": 72819,
         "ModifyIndex": 72819
     },
     "anotherOneBitesTheDust": {
         "ID": "anotherOneBitesTheDust",
         "Service": "anotherOneBitesTheDust",
         "Tags": ["{\"Type\" : \"service type\", \"Description\": \"ddfadf\"}"],
         "Address": "www.google.com",
         "Port": 80,
         "EnableTagOverride": false,
         "CreateIndex": 72465,
         "ModifyIndex": 72465
     },
     "newService": {
         "ID": "newService",
         "Service": "newService",
         "Tags": ["{\"Type\" : \"service type\", \"Description\": \"ddfadf\"}"],
         "Address": "www.google.com",
         "Port": 80,
         "EnableTagOverride": false,
         "CreateIndex": 72389,
         "ModifyIndex": 72389
     }
  }
}

nock("http://10.244.68.3:8500")
    .get('/v1/catalog/node/services')
    .reply(200, consulResponse);
 });

it("returns a status code of 200 when the services domain is queried", function(done) {
    queryConsul(function(err, res){
      console.log(res);
      expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200, done);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

so after more digging we figured it out. We totally changed our code and used this awesome npm(node package manager)

The request-promise gem...(make sure to add "json: true" to the options

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request-promise')


router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index')
});

router.get('/data', function(req, res, next){
  var options = {
    uri: 'http://10.244.68.3:8500/v1/catalog/node/services',
    json: true
};
  request(options).then(function(result){
    res.send(result)
  }).catch(function(err){
    res.send(err)
  })
 })


module.exports = router;
```

Below is how we created our test to hit this route("/data"), create a mock and give us back what we would expect

```
var expect = require("chai").expect;
var nock = require("nock");
var app = require('../../../app');
var request = require("supertest")

var consulResponse

describe("Consul API Queries", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    consulResponse =
    {
     "Node": {
         "Node": "Services",
         "Address": "some_address",
         "TaggedAddresses": null,
         "CreateIndex": 72389,
         "ModifyIndex": 72819
     },
     "Services": {
         "OneBitesTheDust": {
             "ID": "OneBitesTheDust",
             "Service": "OneBitesTheDust",
             "Tags": ["{\"Type\" : \"service type\", \"Description\":      \"ddfadf\"}"],
             "Address": "www.google.com",
             "Port": 80,
             "EnableTagOverride": false,
             "CreateIndex": 72819,
             "ModifyIndex": 72819
         },
         "anotherOneBitesTheDust": {
             "ID": "anotherOneBitesTheDust",
             "Service": "anotherOneBitesTheDust",
             "Tags": ["{\"Type\" : \"service type\", \"Description\": \"ddfadf\"}"],
             "Address": "www.google.com",
             "Port": 80,
             "EnableTagOverride": false,
             "CreateIndex": 72465,
             "ModifyIndex": 72465
         },
         "newService": {
             "ID": "newService",
             "Service": "newService",
             "Tags": ["{\"Type\" : \"service type\", \"Description\": \"ddfadf\"}"],
             "Address": "www.google.com",
             "Port": 80,
             "EnableTagOverride": false,
             "CreateIndex": 72389,
             "ModifyIndex": 72389
         }
      }
    }

    nock("http://10.244.68.3:8500")
        .get('/v1/catalog/node/services')
        .reply(200, consulResponse);
  });

  it("returns a status code of 200 when the services domain is    queried", () => {
    var scope = nock("http://10.244.68.3:8500")
        .get('/v1/catalog/node/services')
        .reply(200, "no way are we getting this to work");
    expect(scope.interceptors[0].statusCode).to.equal(200);
  });


  it("gets the data from consul", (done) => {
    request(app).get('/data')
        .expect(consulResponse, done)

  })

});
```

The issue was that request doesn't hand promises as is so you need the request-promise gem to get this going. Once you get this going you should be good to go!